# How do I transition into the late game?

Tags: metal-slugs-defense

Up until now I've been relying on a steady stream of grenade spam mixed with Fios and Nadias to complete most missions.  However I'm starting to have difficultly completing the NW America emergency mission where a ton of mechanical units are wrecking my grenadiers.  I can hold them off early for a while but eventually they get critical mass and destroy me.  How do I transition into the late game where grenade spam stops working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't use grenadiers at all anymore, they were great early game, and are great for freeing POW as you can make them so fast but they don't have the health or DPS for the later stages. Don't bother making them.

Instead in this part of the game I rely more on the bazooka soldiers. They deal ranged damage as standard and their special can take out most of the light vehicles and tanks, if you time the special after their regular attack you get 4 bazooka shots in a row.

Try and get your bazooka troopers behind a sandbag wherever possible, it can be beneficial to fire off the special early to stop them moving so they wait behind the sandbag until targets are in range.

Try and get 2 or 3 bazookas to fend off the vehicles and get shield troops in front of them if your sandbags are getting destroyed or the units are getting killed before you can push through the incoming troops.
Gatling troops are great support if you have the AP to spend.

If things are going well you should be gaining AP from destroying units and over time, and you'll end up with more than you can spend, when this happens spend it on a higher damage unit like the DI-COKKA or an of the slug variants. This will help you push forward and they'll soak up some damage.

If you are really struggling consider freeing more POWs on the earlier levels for bonuses, for example freeing LVL1 POWs will increase the rate you get AP.

Comment: bazooka units are working out great so far, thanks!

Comment: Fyi The new bazooka unit is awesome.  Much tougher than the old one for only 10 more ap

Comment: If you have some medals to spare the spear throwing "Native" unit is also great for such a low cost unit.

Answer (score 1):

Grenadier aren t worth it at this point of the game, if you have medals (if you didn t used them to get items or other units), I reccomend you to take Ralph: his basic attack is a (not so) long range zone attack, and his special will wreck almost any mechanical units.

Coupled with Nadia (only close contact, but incredibly fast and resistant), you now have only two units to upgrade, and that duo can wreck pieces of a lot of NPC army. (I don t work that well in Wifi VS).

All other good advices have already be told by Amicable : )